# ObjectiveC UIBezierPath path close issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I try to hexagon and I have some issue in the close path.

Here is my hexagon, and the close path is not smooth.
[image]

Here is my drawing code

```
    CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
//  [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
//  [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinBevel];
    [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinMiter];
//  CGFloat dashes[] = {6, 2};
//  [path setLineDash:dashes count:2 phase:0];
//  [path stroke];

    CGFloat radians = 100.0;
    NSInteger num = 6;
    CGFloat interval = 2*M_PI/num;

    NSInteger initX = radians*cosf(interval);
    NSInteger initY = radians*sinf(interval);

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(location.x - semiWidth + initX, location.y - semiHeight + initY)];
    for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        CGFloat x = radians*cosf(i*interval);
        CGFloat y = radians*sinf(i*interval);
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(location.x - semiWidth + x, location.y - semiHeight + y)];
    }
    [path closePath];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0f;
```

Also I try to use different options as following with no luck

```
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinBevel];
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinMiter];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not making your first point (the point you move-to) the same way you're making your other points (the points you line-to).

```
NSInteger initX = radians*cosf(interval);
NSInteger initY = radians*sinf(interval);
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
    location.x - semiWidth + initX, location.y - semiHeight + initY)];
```

Instead, make the first point completely parallel with the others:

```
CGFloat x = radians*cosf(0*interval);
CGFloat y = radians*sinf(0*interval);
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(
    location.x - semiWidth + x, location.y - semiHeight + y)];
```

That's exactly the same as what you'll do later with `i*interval`, and to emphasize that parallelism, I've written `0` as `0*interval`. Here's what I ended up with:

[image]

Comment: Also, you only need to `addLineToPoint:` for 5 points, not 6. `closePath` will draw a line from your final point to the first point in the curve.